# Linux how to install mdump msend

Tags: linux, redhat

Which Linux package has **mdump / msend** utility?

I am running on Redhad Enterprise 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing it in the base server, supplementary, or optional channels.  (Or even the EPEL repository.)

> yum provides */msend
> No matches found.
>
> yum provides */mdump
> No matches found.

It looks like you are to download the binaries from the maintainer.

From the man page:

> mdump may be obtained from: ftp://saf.bio.caltech.edu/pub/software/linux_or_unix_tools/

[Manual Page - mdump(1)](http://saf.bio.caltech.edu/pub/software/linux_or_unix_tools/mdump.html)

I didn't see any thing obvious for msend...

Comment: I believe this is the wrong utility. The OP is looking for the multicast networking `mdump` utility.

Answer (score 3):

The [Informatica MTools package is available here](https://community.informatica.com/solutions/1470).

It provides the `msend`, `mdump` and `mpong` (multicast ping) utilities.

Usage information is here:
https://community.informatica.com/solutions/1470

Comment: This is the link you want:
https://marketplace.informatica.com/listings/cloud/solutions/informatica_mtools.html

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a package search in Redhat? I'd search for those tools and install the proper package then.